# Indicating 'ephemeral questions' section in an FAQ

Tags: word-choice

Granted that entries in an FAQ are subject to change; but say I want to have a separate section for questions that are really only going to be relevant for a very short time - say, a software product version upgrade and questions pertinent to the transition.

I'm looking for something like 'ephemeral questions', or to indicate in some way that this section is reserved for topics that are more fleeting or transient in time. What are my options in this case, either a single word or even a longer phrase (but commonly used in this context)?

---

For context; this is a general purpose FAQ/KB for a piece of software that addresses:

- Initial usage and reasons for adoption (why should I choose X? etc.)
- Data management & access policies
- Troubleshooting steps
- Planned features, maybe with ETA
- etc ...
- 'Ephemeral' questions which would likely mostly be a mix of troubleshooting & future plans that are relevant for the immediate present: e.g. *What are the changes in ACL requirements for next week's release?*. Basically, something with enough customer interest to have a question on it; but not needed long-term.

Comment: We really need more context about the type of document you are writing, but "Release Notes" comes to mind, in that they typically discuss information pertinent to this release only.

Comment: @Jim: Added a bit of context; it would contain questions on 'to release shortly' features but could also be upcoming planned outage etc.

Comment: “Change notes” is another term sometimes used

Comment: Maybe "Hot FAQs"? *Hot* here having the definition: Most recent; new or fresh.

Comment: @JLG: That's an interesting idea; but there is also a 'popular' section so having 'Hot' there (which can also mean popular) would be confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the alliterative **Fleeting FAQ**.

It sounds catchy; plus, *fleeting* is defined as *existing for only a short time*, which aptly describes the questions on that segment of the board.

I'll add one caveat: perhaps there should be a subheading that describes what a *Fleeting FAQ* is, because the term isn't standard industry nomenclature.  By itself, it's likely to be met with a few furrowed eyebrows of confusion.  Adequately described, however, it should be understood just fine:

[image]

(Even if you decide to go with something else, I still think it's a good idea to add a brief explanation, because I'm not sure if there's an existing, commonly-used term for what you're wanting to do.)

Comment: Nice! Reminds me of Fleetwood Mac :)

Comment: Accepting this as its the best suggestion among the answers so far, and the explanation part is a useful idea.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for something like "FAQ of the week". Succinct and easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a separate "FAQ" and "Notice Board"?

Comment: The content of these questions will be repeated in other channels too (on website, so it could be counted as 'notice board'), but I'm specifically looking to incorporate it into the FAQ as I want it to be a one stop source of info in most cases.